# Use 'df -h' to check % remaining disk space of a specific folder

Tags: bash, shell, linux-disk-free

I am using '**df -h**' command to get disk space details in my directory and it gives me response as below :

[image]

Now I want to be able to do this check automatically through some batch or script - so I am wondering, if I will be able to check disk space only for specific folders which I care about, as shown in image - I am only supposed to check for **/nas/home** that it does not go above 75%.

How can I achieve this ? Any help ?

---

My work till now:

I am using

```
df -h > DiskData.txt
```

... this outputs to a text file

```
grep "/nas/home" "DiskData.txt"
```

... which gives me the output:

```
*500G  254G  247G  51% /nas/home*
```

Now I want to be able to search for the number previous or right nearby '%' sign (51 in this case) to achieve what I want.

Comment: Yes, you can do check. But what do you want to do if it's more than 75% ?
You can write bash script and put it to crontab, so you can automate periodical check

Comment: I want to actually send a mail that it is more than 75% but as of now an echo would do, check the updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command will give you percentage of /nas/home directory

```
df /nas/home | awk '{ print $4 }' | tail -n 1| cut -d'%' -f1
```

So basically you can use store as value in some variable and then apply if else condition.

```
var=`df /nas/home | awk '{ print $4 }' | tail -n 1| cut -d'%' -f1`
if(var>75){
#send email
}
```

Comment: **df /nas/home | awk '{ print $5 }' | tail -n 1| cut -d'%' -f1**

gives - _/nas/home_  not **51**

Comment: can you provide output of following command
    
'df /nas/home'

Comment: Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
d2cnas:/dev_home
                     524288000 266297856 257990144  51% /nas/home

Comment: the above is the output for df /nas/home

Comment: I have updated my solution. try once now. use df /nas/home | awk '{ print $4 }' | tail -n 1| cut -d'%' -f1

Comment: I have one more question, can something like this _df /nas/home | awk '{ print $4 }' | tail -n 1| cut -d'%' -f1_ be done in windows command prompt ?

Comment: you can use `df /nas/home|awk '/Filesystem/{getline;print $4}'` or `df /nas/home|awk '/Filesystem/{getline;print $3}'` no need to use multiple pipes

Answer (score 3):

another variant:

```
df --output=pcent /nas/home | tail -n 1 | tr -d '[:space:]|%'
```

**output=pcent** - show only percent value (for coreutils => 8.21 )

Comment: share your output pls

Comment: version coreutils?

Comment: df: unrecognized option '--output=pcent'
Try `df --help' for more information.

Comment: u have version coreutils less than 8.21 (u can check with `df --version`)

Answer (score 1):

A more concise way without extensive piping could be:

```
df -h /nas/home | perl -ane 'print substr $F[3],0,-1 if $.==2'
```

Returns: `51` for your example.